# Why isn't my List populating properly? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to populate my list with numbers from 1 to and including 100.

However, the list won't populate as such. If you run the code you will see that I'm populating my list with single characters of numbers, so when I get into double digits... Things don't go so well.

Please, if you'd change my approach in anyway, let me know. I will be very grateful to say the least.

Here's my code:

```
myList = []

i =0

while len(myList) < 100: 
    i += 1
    myList += str(i)

print (myList)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you are initialising myList, and to show the output From the code in your question when you print myList (Maybe use 20 instead of 100)?

Comment: I would use `while i < 100`, rather than checking the length of the string. Also, to add an item to a list, use the `append` method :)

Comment: @barny I have updated

Comment: What’s the output from the print? Use this code.

Comment: @Ed Ward you genius thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```py
myList = []

i =0

while len(myList) < 100: 
    i += 1
    myList += [str(i)] # or just use myList.append(i)

print (myList)
```

- What happening in your case is when you do `myList += str(i)` what you are adding to list is not single value but instead array of characters.
- Let me explain it with example.

```py
>>> lst = []
>>> lst += str(123)
>>> lst
['1', '2', '3']
>>> lst += [str(123)]
>>> lst
['1', '2', '3', '123']
```

- As you can see str(123) will be converted to iterable list `['1', '2', '3']` first then it will be added to list.
- But in second case your right hand side `[str(123)]` is already a list so. Python will just add one element to your list.

PS: It's suggested to use the `append` method instead of `+=` operator for better performance. As in `+=` operator python needs to create a whole new list and iterate it for just one element.

Comment: *Please* use `append`. `[str(i)]` has to create an entirely new `list` object just for `list.__iadd__` to iterate over, then that list gets discarded.

Comment: @chepner yes added append method in comment

Comment: That makes it sound like an acceptable alternative, rather than what you *should* be using.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

Use a basic list comprehension with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?#the-range-function):

```py
myList = [ str(i) for i in range(1,101) ]
```

The argument is `101` so it includes `100`:

> The given end point is never part of the generated sequence ...
>   (from that link)

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = []

i =0

while len(myList) < 100: 
    i += 1
    myList.append(str(i))

print (myList)
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `myList.append` instead of `+= myList`.